# Bit vector and bitset

Tags: c++, stl, bitset, bitvector

What is the difference between bit-vector and bitset container of stl ? Please explain.
To my understanding bitset is the implementation of the concept of bitvector am I right or wrong? What are the other ways to implement bit vector?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`bit_vector` has the same interface as an `std::vector`, and is optimised for space. It not a part of standard C++. This [documentation](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/bit_vector.html) claims it is close to an STL `vector<bool>`, which presumably is quite close to a standard C++ `std::vector<bool>`.

[std::bitset](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset) is fixed size, and has a different interface.

Answer (score 1):

They're different. A `std::bitset` has a fixed size known at compile time. This allows it to be implemented very efficiently. A bit vector (I assume you mean `std::vector<bool>`) can vary in size like any other `std::vector`.